# Dragfill in Datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to copy datagrid columns like dragfill/ Auto Fill feature to fill cells with data that follows a pattern or that is based on data in previous cells like in excel.

[image: autofill screenshot]

Comment: you would NOT want to **copy** data using dragfill. users associate dragfill with **data interpolation**.  add a context menu with cut/copy/paste or something else;

Comment: @jberger: Thanks for your comment. Basically I wants to implement drag-fill only for copy operation or number increment which I would implement copy/number increment in C# code. 

Is there any styles available(which changes cursors, show cell selections etc)for datagrid which emulate drag-fill?